# Implementing an iterator for a set of handles

Tags: c++

I'm working with an awkward C library interface for a database containing a set of objects. The objects have a type and lets say that objects of type A contain a set of B objects and so on. Access to an object is via a handle which are defined as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
    int handle;
} AHandleT; 


typedef struct
{
    int handle;
} BHandleT;
```

To iterate over an A object's B children, the following functions are used:

```
ReturnT getB(AHandleT /*in*/, BHandleT* /*out*/)
ReturnT getBNext(BHandleT /*in*/, BHandleT* /*out*/)
```

Likewise for iterating over a set of B objects:

```
ReturnT getC(BHandleT handle/*in*/, CHandleT* subHandle/*out*/)
ReturnT getCNext(CHandleT handle/*in*/, CHandleT* next/*out*/)
```

In order to work with this interface from C++ I have made the following iterator and I would appreciate your advice with regard to its implementation. Additionally, do you think this is a good approach? Keep in mind that I'm quite new to C++ and I will be writing my code using TDD.

```
template<class HandleT>
class HandleIterator 
{
public:
    typedef ReturnT (*GetNext)(HandleT, HandleT*);

    HandleIterator(): m_isLast(true)
    {
    }

    template<class ParentHandleT>
    HandleIterator(const ParentHandleT parentHandle, ReturnT (*getFirstChild)(ParentHandleT, HandleT*), GetNext getNext): m_isLast(false), m_getNext(getNext)
    {
        ReturnT rc = getFirstChild(parentHandle, &m_currentHandle);
        if(rc == NotExisting)
        {
            m_isLast = true;
        }
    }

    void operator++()
    {
        ReturnT rc = m_getNext(m_currentHandle, &m_currentHandle);
        if(rc == NotExisting)
        {
            m_isLast = true;
        }
    }

    void operator++(int)
    {
        ++(*this);
    }

    const HandleT& operator*() const
    {
        return m_currentHandle;
    }

    const HandleT* operator->() const
    {
        return &m_currentHandle;
    }

    friend bool operator==(const HandleIterator& left, const HandleIterator& right)
    {
        return left.m_isLast == right.m_isLast;
    }

    friend bool operator!=(const HandleIterator& left, const HandleIterator& right)
    {
        return !(left == right);
    }

protected:
    HandleT m_currentHandle;
    bool m_isLast;
    GetNext m_getNext;
};
```

Once I have a handle, I can then get the data contained within the object using functions of the following form, from the C interface:

```
ReturnT getAName(AHandleT)
ReturnT getBName(BHandleT)
ReturnT getBOnlyProprty(BHandleT)
```

But that's the next stage.

etc.

Comment: Would you consider to invert the pattern? For example a function  EnumHandles() that takes a callback

Comment: Your increment operators return nothing. `operator++()` usually returns a reference to `this` and `operator++(int)` returns by value.

Comment: It looks a sensible approach, and well implemented apart from the `operator++` issues @jrok identified.  Your question might fit better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com - could you try asking there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is quite good, especially for a beginner.

Just a couple of remarks:

- In the constructor, why pass `getFirstChild` instead of providing the first child directly ?
- The canonical signature for `++` are `T& operator++()` and `T operator++(int)`
- `==` should compare more than `m_isLast`, otherwise it's confusing. Cannot you compare the handles too ?

Finally, when implementing an iterator, consider inheriting from `std::iterator`. It does not have any virtual method but provides the `typedef` that are usually expected in an iterator and will remind you that you need to pick a category: `std::forward_iterator_tag` here, most probably.